# UICollectionViewCell remain black when used with SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I want to fetch images from Instagram API and then show them in my iOS app's `UICollectionView` using `SDWebImage`. But after I load the image to cells the cells remain black.

Here's the code within `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`:

```
let photo = self.photosArray[indexPath.row] as! AnyObject
let photoUrlString = photo.valueForKeyPath("images.standard_resolution.url")! as! String
print(photoUrlString) // properly show the URL 
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: photoUrlString), placeholderImage: nil)
print(cell.frame) // confirmed that the frame is not 0
cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
```

However, the cell remain black on the screen.

I also check it by calling `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()`, then it is wrapped in red screen. But the image was still not displayed on the screen.

How can I display the image on the cell?

### UPDATE

I tried adding `UILabel` to its cell using the same `addSubview:`, the label was displayed correctly. I'm not sure why this is not the case with the image...

Comment: Does it show the image if you set the local image to the image view? `imageView.image = UIImage(named: "my image.jpg")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your UIImageView does not have a frame. Try this:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: cell.contentView.frame.bounds)
```